# Do linearly independent vector fields with vanishing Lie bracket always have integral manifolds which are level sets?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, foliations

Suppose I have a smooth distribution on an open subset of $M = R^n_{++}$ consisting of $n-1$ vector fields $X^i$. I know three things about this distribution:

1. At each point $p \in M$ the set $(X^1_p,\ldots,X^{n-1}_p)$ is linearly independent and so spans an $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of $R^n$.
2. For each pair $i,j, \; 1 \leq i < j \leq n-1, \; [X^i,X^j] = 0$ (so the system is in involution).
3. At each point of $M$ the normal to the subspace spanned by this system is non-negative, with the last coordinate strictly positive.

By 2, Frobenius tells us this system is integrable with its integral manifolds forming a foliation of $M$. I understand this also means that there are local coordinates $x^i$ such that $X^i = \partial/\partial x^i$. I have two questions:

1. In this particular case does there always exist a single function $f: M \rightarrow R$ (smooth or not) such that the integral manifolds (hypersurfaces) are level sets of $f$; i.e. each leaf $L$ of the foliation is of the form $f^{-1}(x)$ for some $x \in R$?
2. Is each leaf $L$ of the foliation globally the graph of some function $h:D \rightarrow R$ (i.e. $L = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},h(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}))$ where $D$ is some domain in $R^{n-1}$?

My sense is that the first statement is not true but (because of the third assumption) that the second is. As to 1., it has been suggested to me that if I looked at the distribution from the perspective of the normal field (i.e. 1-form approach) that my assumption that the Lie bracket vanishes is equivalent to the "well-known" integrability conditions insuring there exists a function f with the required property, but I'm not sure this is right.

I would appreciate any insight into this (surely) simple issue that I'm just not seeing.

**Edit**: In case it helps I can give a concrete example of the vector fields I'm working with when $n=3$. $X^1 = (-m(x_1,x_2,x_3),1, 0), \; X^2 = (-n(x_1,x_2,x_3),0,1)$. Here the smooth functions $m$ and $n$ are strictly positive everywhere on $M$ and bounded away from zero and $\infty$ on every compact subset of $M$. I also simply **impose** the condition $[X^1,X^2] = mn_1 - nm_1 -n_2 +m_3 = 0$. Note that the normal field is $N_{(x_1,x_2,x_3)} = (1,m(x_1,x_2,x_3),n(x_1,x_2,x_3)) \gg 0$.

**Further clarification**: Assumptions on m are, for each fixed $x_2,x_3$ that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}m(x,x_2,x_3) = 0, \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}m(x,x_2,x_3) = \infty$. A similar assumption holds for $n$; i.e. for each fixed $x_1,x_3$ $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}n(x_1,x,x_3) = 0, \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}n(x_1,x,x_3) = \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help either way, but what does it mean to say that a normal space is non-negative?

Comment: What is $R^n_{++}$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: In this case it's the normal vector, (because there are $(n-1)$ linearly independent vectors in the field) so I mean each component is $\geq 0$ and the last one is strictly positive.

Comment: @JackLee: Sorry, strictly positive orthant of $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, or set of $n$-vectors with all coordinates strictly positive.

Comment: BTW, to both of you, this problem has been killing me, any info you can provide (especially on 2.) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I will try the case $n=2$. Consider a field of directions on $(0,\infty)^2$, with the field of normals
$n(x,y) = (n_1(x,y), n_2(x,y))\ $, $n_1\ge 0$, $n_2>0$.

The leafs of the foliations will be the graphs of functions $y = \phi(x)$ solutions of the differential equation

$$a_1 dx + a_2 dy = 0$$
or
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{a_1(x,y)}{a_2(x,y)}$$

(in the case $n=2$, we get an ordinary differential equation, so there are no integrability conditions)

The graphs of different solutions will be the leaves of the foliation.

Note that to get a solution we fix $x_0$, $y_0>0$ and consider the solution that satisfies furthermore $\phi(x_0) = y_0$.  Now, there are in fact $\infty^1$, and not $\infty^2$ such solutions, since for all pairs $(x^*, y^*)$ on the graph of one, we get the same one.
In other words, the family of solutions ( of leaves if you want) depends on $1$ parameter ( something that they tell you in ODE class while hand-waving). However, globally labelling such solutions could be tricky.

To label the solutions( leaves), find a transversal curve $t\mapsto (\psi_1(t), \psi_2(t))$ that intersects each leaf in exactly one point. This has to work globally. (Foliations are  tricky...). Now I think we could consider the transversal $t \mapsto (t, t)$. In this way we'll get a function $f\colon (0, \infty)^2$ with the leaves the level curves. The description of the function is this:

for every $(x_0, y_0)$, the solution of the Cauchy problem
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = - \frac{n_1(x,y)}{n_2(x,y)}, \  y(x_0) = x_0 $$

has a unique fixed point $t = t(x_0, y_0)$. We take $f(x_0, y_0) = t$.

Notes:

1. We see that in this case every level set is a leaf so connected. This is a nice situation, where leaves can be labeled "linearly". However, you can start with a submersion $f$, but whose level sets are not connected. Now, look only at the distribution of hyperplanes, and so at the foliation. All is good, integrable, but trying to write each leaf separately as a level set would be a problem.
2. The case of general $n$ : the Frobenius integrability condition ensure that the solution of the Cauchy-Frobenius problem

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i} = - \frac{a_i(x', y)}{a_n(x',y)}$$
exists locally. Extend it all the way and get the graphs as the leaves of the foliations. Again, we have to label them. Each of the leaves will intersect the diagonal $(t, t, \ldots, t)$ in exactly one point. Now the function $f(x_{01}, \ldots, x_{0n-1}, x_{0n})$ is as follows: the solution $y_{(x'_0, x_{0,n})}$ of

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i} = -\frac{a_i(x',y)}{a_n(x',y)} \ \ ,  y(x'_0) = x_{0n}$$ has a unique "fixed point" $(t,t\ldots, t)$. Define $f((x'_0, x_{0n})=t$.

Comment: I appreciate the response:  Since comments are restricted, I only want to say that the case $n=2$ is one I've already handled (although I can always learn something). The problem I have is in "The case of general $n$". HOW do I prove the solution can be extended "all the way"? My assumption is that, since the leaves of foliations can be twisty and tricky (at least those of non-regular foliations), this can't be true in general. What is it about the assumptions I've made that allows this extension and, if you'd be so kind, can you give me guidance on how to carry it out?

Comment: @user167131: In the case $n=2$. The projection of a leaf might not be the full $(0, \infty)$ ( the solution of the ODE is extended all the way but reaches $\infty$ before $0$. As an example, consider the level set of a function with gradient with positive components ( increasing in $x$ and in $y$), $f(x,y) = \frac{2}{\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}}$. The level sets of this are of the form $\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{y} = c$. and the projection is $(\frac{1}{c}, \infty)$. But that should not be a deterrent- that the leaves do not project onto the full thing.  Also, my knowledge of foliations is  limited.

Comment: I added some clarification to the question because in the case $n=2$ those additional assumptions allowed me to conclude that the solution path did not "escape to infinity" at finite $x$. So we had, for each leaf, a strictly monotonically decreasing curve  on $(0,\infty)$, going from $\infty$ to $0$. I then considered the point on each leaf where the slope of the path was $-1$ and took as $f$ the value of $x$ at which the tangent hit the $x$-axis. It worked fine. But once I get to $n > 2$ I stop dead; while I have confidence 2. is true, I'd like to know why and how to prove it. Thanks again.

Comment: Almost there, I can see how through each point of the transversal (t,t,..t) there passes a unique leaf of the foliation, but I can't see how you can show that the transversal passes through EVERY leaf (might there be leaves which do not intersect the transversal at all).